# Graphql server side how to work with schemas

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I'm using apollo server for graphql server.

The data I have

```
const books = [
{
    id: 1,
    title: "Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets",
    author: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Jurassic Park",
    author: 2
  }
];
const authors = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "J.K. Rowling",
    age: "26",
    bookId: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Michael Crichton",
    age: "27",
    bookId: 1
  }
];
```

The Schema I have defined

```
const typeDefs = gql`
  type Book {
    title: String
    author: Author
  }
  type Author {
    name: String
    age: String
  }
  type Query {
    books(id: ID!): [Book]
    author: [Author]
  }
`;
```

The Resolver I have coded:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    books: (_, { id }) => books
    author: () => authors
  }
};
```

Request made in the GrahqlTool

```
query {
  books(id: 1){
    title
    author {
        name
        age
    }
  }
}
```

The response I'm getting back

```
{
  "data": {
    "books": []
  }
}
```

What I am expecting is

```
{
  "data": {
    "books": [
      {
        "title": "Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets",
        "author": {
           name: "J.K. Rowling",
           age: "26"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How to define a schema for this scenario? Help me with writing schema to achieve the above result. ( I have edited my question please reconsider)

Comment: Args are passed in as the second parameter to the resolver, not the first.

Comment: Can you help me with schema definition?

Comment: If you're just returning the `books` variable inside the resolver as shown and your type for the `books` field is `[Book]` as shown, there's no reason you should be getting an empty array back. Either the snippets here don't reflect your actual code or there's something else going on. Try creating a reproducable example using [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io) and posting the link here.

Comment: Yeah.. will do that. I have edited my result im getting. It not empty array on book but author object elements with null values

Comment: You need to provide a resolver for the author field. The property `author` on each Book object is just an id. GraphQL does not know it needs to resolve it to a different value unless you tell it explicitly.

Comment: Can you help with the Author Resolver?

Comment: I have added new resolver. The code is here https://github.com/mounikakella/graphql-server-example/blob/master/index.js. Still getting null values for keys in author

Comment: Got the solution https://github.com/mounikakella/graphql-server-example/blob/master/index.js